# how to add a variable amount of empty dimensions to pytorch tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I am looking for a more elegant way to perform the following reshape operation:

```py
import torch
t1 = torch.ones((1,2,3))
t2 = torch.ones((4,))
res = t2.view(-1, *[1]*t1.ndim)  # add t1.ndim empty dimensions
```

I feel that the expression `*[1]*t1.ndim` is overly complicated to add a specific amount of empty dimensions.

Expected result:

```py
res.shape == (4, 1, 1, 1)
```